# Balance array of numbers to equal 1

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that given an array like

```
var a = [
    0.0015974718789698097
    ,0.755383581038094
    ,0.13950473043946954
    ,0.0011978091842754731
    ,0.005126875727346068
    ,0.0042250281407886295
    ,0.0001720958819913952
    ,0.0047584144830165875
    ,0.0835073272489086
    ,0.00016098907002300275
    ,0.0028037075787230655
    ,0.0014378579473690483
    ,0.00012411138102484662
]
```

or

```
var a = [
    0.33333333333333333
    ,0.33333333333333333
    ,0.33333333333333333
]
```

or

```
var a = [
    0.166666666666666
    ,0.166666666666666
    ,0.3
    ,0.3333333333333333
]
```

It round each number to 3 decimal places while keeping the sum of all the values is still equal to 1.0.

The way I imagine it would do this is by taking the difference of the new sum and the expected sum and distribute the difference while maintaining the relative distribution as close as possible. I can only think of an iterative approach and wanted to see what other solutions people can come up with

It's important to notice that the very last value of `0.00012411138102484662` will round to 0.000 but that doesn't it mean it should never get a piece of the difference, because the distribution it wants to maintain is the unrounded distribution, not the current distribution after rounding to 3 decimal places nor after iteration of balancing

Comment: "round to three decimal places" doesn't really make sense in a world of binary floating point.

Comment: "The sum" is not even well-defined when it comes to floating point. To give you an idea, `a.reduce(function(p,c){return p+c},0)` gives me `1.0000000000000002` and not `1`. This might be different if summed up in a different order though.

Comment: These caveats are apart of the problem - my hope is that floating point error can be ignored if the end result will only have an accuracy of 3 decimal places

Comment: In regards to floating point, I would think it to be acceptable to convert the decimal values to an integer counterpart (as big as you can fit in a 32bit integer) and uses that to do arithmetic then finally converting back to decimal at the end. I think that would work ?

Comment: "Here is what I came up with, looking for improvements or potential errors" Sounds like what you have is working as intended? If so, this question sounds like a good candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Stack Overflow isn't a great place for open ended questions with multiple (equally valid)  answers.

Comment: Asked it to be moved, I originally didn't have code but decided attempt it myself

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on rounding each of the values in the array to the 3rd decimal and adding them all up, Then here's what you need to do. You will need to get each number of the array into a loop and make that number to the fixed 3rd decimal by doing `.toFixed(3)` and parsing that to a float and adding it to a variable which will loop and the variable's value will change. Like this:

```
var int = 0;
a.forEach(number => { int += parseFloat(number.toFixed(3)) })
int // 1
```